# Implement search across application

Tags: angularjs

I have one search text box on top bar of my angular application. Something like following.

[image]

User can type some keyword and search across application. User will have list of links with some description.

I can implement it at client side as well as at server side. I am using **angular** at client side and **.net** at server side.

Can anyone suggest me some framework available to implement these? It can be client side or server side.

I can implement it from scratch, that is not an issue. But first I want to go through solution already available.

Please suggest.

Comment: You may try elasticsearch in the server side, I think it has a .net API support.

Comment: Simple use type-ahead which bring you data from server end(.asp net) and return json which you can alter at client at.
http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-typeahead-widget-with-angularjs/

Comment: *"But first I want to go through solution already available."* -> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, **software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on many things:

- if you have very little content to search in, you may opt for a full client-side solution, but that's usually not a very good idea
- if you need full-text search, and at least basic semantic features (make sure e.g.  "trees" matches "tree"), you should really have a look at Elasticsearch which is pretty easy to setup, and has very good .NET bindings (look for "NEST")
- if you want fuzzy suggest on keywords (e.g. tags associated on documents) and are open to paying a service to handle it for you, I can suggest Algolia (http://www.algolia.com) which is a SaaS for search and suggest and should be very reasonably priced if you are in an enterprise environment and not a high-traffic website. We are using it for that use case and we are extremely happy with it.

Comment: Yes you can pay, but you can't install it by yourself, in the contrary of Elasticsearch... :-/

Comment: @dhavalcengg: Elasticsearch or as it seems you're on .net you may as well be on MS SQL which also has full text search for the same purpose.